# Is it possible to automate windows application?

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, ui-automation

I have some test cases to validate whether the user details are appearing when applications like (SQL Server, Bitbucket, RDC, PuTTY etc. ) are launched. I want to understand if this scenario can be automated through PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

https://wasp.codeplex.com

WASP is a PowerShell snapin for Windows Automation tasks like selecting windows and controls and sending mouse and keyboard events. We have automation cmdlets like Select-Window, Select-Control, Send-Keys, Send-Click, Get-WindowPosition, Set-WindowPosition, Set-WindowActive, Remove-Window ... etc.

Our goal is to enable you to accomplish most Windows GUI Automation scripting from inside PowerShell, without resorting to specialized (and expensive) scripting tools.

Just to be clear, don't expect any "click to record" functionality ... but do expect to be able to automatically tile windows, send mouse clicks and keystrokes, and in general, automate those tasks that you would normally not be able to do from a console.

Comment: do you have any documentation relating to WASP usage?